# Populate Combo Box in Outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I have my combobox in outsystems and its populated by Integers that corresponds to each months' names, How can I display month names on my combobox? 1-12 -> January-> December respectively? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is probably to create a Static Entity called "Month" and **set its Id "Is Autonumber" attribute to "No"**. Then add 12 records, one for each month, specifying its (explicit) Id to the "number of the month" (i.e. "January" has Id=1, "February" has id=2 and so on).

[image]

Then on the screen use a Combo Box, setting its "Source Entity" to "Month" and its "Variable" to a screeen variable of the type "Month Identifier". On submit this month indentifier variable will hold the Id of the selected month (which is the number you want).